# focus not working on tab navigation

Tags: css, focus

please correct me if I am asking this wrong,

here is a little css tab navigation, the links will not focus when controlling the tabs boxes, but they focus normally. for example.

this will not focus.

```
  <a href="#one" class="won">doesn't focus</a>
```

this one will focus

```
  <a href="#">does focus</a>
```

here is the full example I am struggling with.  www.blackbeltweb.net/focus.html

Comment: [They both focus for me](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2Yu5R/).

Answer (score 2):

You have an `outline:none` on the `.won` class. Hence the focus is not highlighted with the dotted outline like it would be by default.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in Chrome. Maybe you can try setting the [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tabIndex)

Comment: ok, i tryed with chrome, and realized I have aproched this wrong, I wanted the links to highlight when clicked, but apparently focus is for tabbing through links. the links don't highlight in chromium when clicked and that is what I am aiming for.

Comment: ...in that case you want a:active

Comment: @henryalbert Maybe you want the css pseudo selector a:active.